# Order result following the order of an array of words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a flag in the database, that flag can be a set of words, for example: 'a_word', 'b_word', 'c_word', 'z_word' and I want to sort the results of a query following a custom order of those words, for example: ['z_word', 'b_word', 'a_word','c_word'].

I want (if it exists) something like:

```
User.order(flag: ['z_word', 'b_word', 'a_word','c_word'])
```

Does this exist? It's similar to postgres order by case.

Comment: I don't know a concise answer, but off the top of my head, I think you have three options: #1 write your SQL `order by` string directly (not database-agnostic); #2 add something like the [squeel gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel), assuming it can do custom complex ordering (never used it, not sure), #3 sort it in ruby afterwards using [`sort!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort-21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `CASE` in your `select` thus naming the column and then use it in your `order` clause, like so:

```
case_str = "CASE WHEN users.flag = 'z_word' THEN 0"
case_str += "    WHEN users.flag = 'b_word' THEN 1"
case_str += "    WHEN users.flag = 'a_word' THEN 2"
case_str += "    WHEN users.flag = 'c_word' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END AS sorty_flag"

User.select("*, ?", case_str).order("sorty_flag").to_a
```

The `?` is in there to avoid SQL injection...